# Regular Expression for matching words on each line except the first

Tags: php, regex

```
WT01-B01-2 WT01-B01-6 WT01-B01-1 
WT01-B01-3 WT01-B01-6 WT01-B01-1 
WT01-B01-4 WT01-B01-6 WT01-B01-1 
WT01-B01-11 WT01-B01-9 
WT01-B01-12 WT01-B01-8 
WT01-B01-13 WT01-B01-8 
WT01-B01-14 WT01-B01-8 
WT01-B01-17 WT01-B01-16 WT01-B01-19 WT01-B01-18 WT01-B01-20 WT01-B01-21 
WT01-B01-18 WT01-B01-16 WT01-B01-19 WT01-B01-20 WT01-B01-21 WT01-B01-17 
WT01-B01-19 WT01-B01-16 WT01-B01-18 WT01-B01-20 WT01-B01-21 WT01-B01-17 
WT01-B01-20 WT01-B01-16 WT01-B01-19 WT01-B01-18 WT01-B01-21 WT01-B01-17 
WT01-B01-21 WT01-B01-19 WT01-B01-18 WT01-B01-20 WT01-B01-17
```

What I need to do is in php, I need to store words in array. A typical word looks like WT01-B01-2. I want all the words except the first word on each lines. I tried a lot, but couldn't do it. I am new to programming and regex. Let me know if I am missing anything. Thanks

Comment: assume that's one string, explode on new line, then loop and explode on space, then implode discarding array 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `(?<!^|[\w\d-\n\r])([\w\d-]+)(?!=[\w\d-])`

Answer (score 1):

Since your requirement is that it should not be the first letter on the line, you can simply make do with this:

```
preg_match_all( "/ WT([0-9]+)-B([0-9]+)-[0-9]+/", $input, $matches );
```

The space requires that it is preceded by another word and will not be the first word on the line. The matches array will contain each word along with the numbers.

Comment: worked! Thanks a lot. Its skipping the first word as you described. That was really quick. Thanks again